# Working with JSON in Python - Cannot Get to Correct Data Level

Tags: python, json

Working with the Pocket API dataset and trying to parse out details about each item.  Unfortunately, I am stuck at looking at "list" data and not the individual details for each item.

JSON

```
"status": 1,
"complete": 1,
"list": {
    "2872254473": {
        "item_id": "2872254473",
        "resolved_id": "2872254473",
        "given_url": "https://i.redd.it/g0iq3upzffe41.jpg",
        "given_title": "i.redd.it",
        "favorite": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "time_added": "1580666841",
        "time_updated": "1580667500",
        "time_read": "1580667500",
        "time_favorited": "0",
        "sort_id": 0,
        "resolved_title": "",
        "resolved_url": "https://i.redd.it/g0iq3upzffe41.jpg",
        "excerpt": "",
        "is_article": "0",
        "is_index": "0",
        "has_video": "0",
        "has_image": "2",
        "word_count": "0",
        "lang": "",
        "domain_metadata": {
            "name": "Reddit",
            "logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/reddit.com?size=800",
            "greyscale_logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/reddit.com?size=800&greyscale=true"
        },
```

Python Code

```
import json
with open('2. JSON Data (Pocket Articles Tagged TIL)2.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

print(data)
print('----')
print(type(data))
print(type(data['list']))

for item in data['list']:
 print(item)
```

The issue is I can't seem to use data['item'] or data['list']['item'].  I am trying to query the added_date and item_id for each individual item.

Comment: What is the python interpreter output for these prints?

Comment: there's one more level b/w `list` and `item_id`...do `data['list']['2872254473']['item_id']`

Comment: Did you try `data['list'][item]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code to get each items id and time_added:

```
for list_key, value in data['list'].items():
    print(list_key, value['item_id'], value['time_added'])
```